# Get position of the cursor when it's over the video control bar

Tags: javascript, html5-video, projekktor

I need to get the position pointed by the user's mouse cursor when he's hovering the control bar. How do I do it ?

Comment: Have any code for us?

Comment: I'm looking into this http://www.projekktor.com/docs/events to find out a way to get what I need, no code so far since nothing has been tested

Comment: I see a `mousemove` but IDK if that can help; I don't see a way to specify an event `onmouseover` over control bar only and not the whole video (unless the control bar is a separate HTML element). Or you could create an invisible `div` the size of the control bar and make a `onmouseover` event for that. Kind of hacky. :P

Comment: If I do it manually I won't be able to be specific enough for what I need to do. I need the exact moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event "seek" does the job ;)
you should add a listner to your instance player :

```js
player.addListener('seek', seekListener);
```

Then define this function:

```js
var seekListener=function(Obj) {    
   $('#mouseclick').html(myPlayer.getPosition())
}
```